# Are the points on a closed surface included in the volume enclosed by it?

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions, greens-functions

[image: G-Green's function]

Green's theorem is used when finding a general solution for Poisson's or Laplace's equation. The Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions assure unique potential. While finding a general formula that can be used when Dirichlet condition is in use , Green's function, because of its free part, is set to zero on the surface. But this setting appears to raise a question whose origin is described in the image. Please have a look at the image and resolve my query...
In other words, the question is- Is volume a closed or open set of points?

Comment: the thing in the first integral that looks like p is 'rho' for volume charge density

Comment: This question would be easier to read if you put the equations into the question text rather than use an image, despite the neat writing on the page.

Comment: Doesn't the writing on page explain the question clearly? I don't know how to write in latex and other languages. As a substitute, I wrote it on page. Is it really unclear to all readers here?

Comment: I would appreciate effort if one edits it in those languages like latex...if handwriting is really bad.

Comment: This sounds like a philosophical question, or a question of definition. What difference does it make physically?

Comment: Suppose for the moment that points on surface are included in the volume then the Laplacian can't be zero. So, the difference it makes is that for the Dirichlet boundary condition you can't set Green function's value at the boundary to be zero.